# асинхронный setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, асинхронность, async-await

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getProcessSetting(this.props.id);
        this.setState({
            params: this.props.store
        })
    }
```

getProcessSetting = это action, в котором получаю даннные. 
Далее пытаюсь записать ответ в state, получаю ошибку.
Как я понял get запрос не сразу возвращает ответ. 
Как переписать так чтобы после того я получил ответ записал в state?

Comment: Можешь ошибку показать, во всяком случае попробуй обернуть в промис свой запрос и в then выполнить setState

Comment: здесь, конечно, проще всего бы было подключить `middleWare` и внутри него сделать действия

Answer (score 0):

Если getProcessSetting это запрос, то можно написать следующим образом:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getProcessSetting(this.props.id).then(result => {
        this.setState({
            params: result
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: вроде был логично, но для того, чтобы Ваш код работал, нужно чтобы `this.props.getProcessSetting(this.props.id)` возвращал **промис**. но `action` ничего не должен возвращать, кроме объекта для **редьюсера**